# Trigger jenkins job via jira-trigger-plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin, jenkins-jira-trigger

I set the jenkins job to trigger via jira-trigger-plugin.
But jenkins job is not triggered although it get the webhook event from JIRA.

I checked things as below.
Jenkins got the webhook event. I checked this on jenkins log.

I tried to set various way to jenkins, but all failed.
So, I want to know how to set jira-trigger

- Test environment

  - JIRA: 6.4.11
  - Jenkins: 2.19
  - jira-trigger-plugin: 0.5.1
- My test case is ...

  - Jenkins Job setting
  - checked: Build when a comment is added to JIRA
  - JQL Filter: project = MY_PROJ AND issuetype = "TYPE1"
  - Comment pattern: build_start
  - I tried to leave a comment("build_start") on the issue among the result of filter(project = MY_PROJ AND issuetype = "TYPE1")

What is wrong as above?

Comment: You should quote the jenkins log where the webhook event is logged. Most probably it is some wrong job configuration in jenkins...

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this symptom.
"JIRA Trigger Configuration" in jenkins setting was wrong.
After modifing the "JIRA root URL", trigger is doing well.